# Gratis Python IDE for commercial use

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, ide, python

My company wants me to code Python.
My company won't pay for a Python IDE.
That won't change.

So, what's currently the most full featured Python IDE which I don't have to pay for and can legally use in a commercial environment?

It must support Python 3 (with at most one configuration option - the path to the Python binary) and be easily installable on Ubuntu 12.04 (preferably a package).

**Must have:** debugger, set breakpoints, run to breakpoint, one step, examine variables, etc.

**Nice to have:** auto completion, Windows version

---

[Update]: [Spyder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyder) looked excellent, but I can't get it to install with Python 3 support :-(
[Update]: I [got it installed (using PIP)](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-on-linux), but can't configure it to use Python 3 -  it's still using Python 2 :-(
[Update]: Same for Eric (and I can't find an Ubuntu package for Eric6)

Comment: What OS platform?

Comment: How well does your muscle memory know the vi and Emacs keybindings?

Comment: Not at all. I haven't seen the need to use either them as my main editor for a decade or two (admittedly I keep a vi cheat sheet for emergencies, but I wouldn't use either on a day to day basis).

Comment: ([Meta discussion re. the "python3" tag](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1047/60).)

Comment: @unforgettableid I thought Emacs wa[s](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?EmacsVsVi) an operating sy[s](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EmacsAsOperatingSystem)tem ;)

Comment: To get Spyder for Python 3, you need to be using `pip3`, not `pip`.  See [my answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/16388/1675) below.

Comment: for PyCharm's free Community Edition in an answer [I've contacted JetBrains support](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/16371/2331)  and they've confirmed that the community edition can be used in a commercial environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) now has a free, **open-source**, apache-licensed "community edition":

> Community Edition FREE
>
> - Lightweight IDE for Python development only
> - Free, open-source, Apache 2 license
> - Intelligent Editor, Debugger, Refactorings, Inspections, VCS integration
> - Project Navigation, Testing support, Customizable UI, Vim key bindings

**Download**: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

It has a **Linux**, Windows and Mac OS X version.

Its Apache 2 license [**should grant you with the commercial use**](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/). I had this confirmed by the Jetbrains support:

> Yes, the Community Edition may be used commercially

Link to **comparison matrix** of editions - including **Graphical Debugger in "free" edition**:

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Basic idea of different editions, from the [FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/FAQ#FAQ-CommunityEdition):

> Basically, the main items missing in Community Edition are detailed web and enterprise support features.

[image: PyCharm GUI]

Disclaimer: I don't personally use an IDE. However, I'd probably choose this if I would. Open-source - check. Features - check. Usability - check. Prettiness - check.

Comment: Are you sure? Why do they offer [a separate commercial](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/buy/) license then?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ OK I am **not** so sure anymore. (updated answer) The commercial license over your link do not bother me, it's the same pay or pay choice for Personal Developers on that page. I based my recommendation on the fact of the Apache 2 license, but I am in no way an expert in licenses. What makes me re-think is [the license comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/buy/license-matrix.jsp). Maybe only open-source projects are covered with the open-license. JetBrains support should be contacted.

Comment: OK, at least you've clarified in the answer now :) I know nothing about licences either!

Comment: I've contacted sales... awaiting answer in 1 business days... (probably 3 days from now)

Comment: The IntelliJ FAQ you link to specifically answers that the Apache license was chosen to enable commercial use as well. The commercial editions of JetBrains' software simply have more features, and most people will need to pay if they want to use that edition. (Admittedly, it's about a different product, but it's the same company and the same license.)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Got answer, `Yes, the Community Edition may be used commercially`. (For reference, my question was: `can someone use the community edition for free in a commercial environment legally?`). Updated answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for updating the answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend Spyder which meets all your requirements:

- Free
- Can be used in commercial environment (it's under the MIT license)
- Supports Python 3
- Cross-platform
- Debugger (with break points, variable inspection, etc.)
- Auto-completion

[image]

---

## Installation for Python 3

To use Spyder for Python 3, you just need v2.3.0 or later.

**Ubuntu 12.10 and later**

You can get this by using `pip3`.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-pyqt4
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

**Ubuntu 12.04**

Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have `python3-pip` in the repositories, but you can get it with `setuptools`,

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4 python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

you can then open Spyder from the launcher (after logging out and in) or from the terminal by typing `spyder3`.

Comment: I really like Spyder & would like to get it working, but ...  E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
E: Unable to locate package python3-qt4

Comment: @Mawg, thanks, I've edited my answer and verified that it works in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Wow!! great service, a pity I could only +1. in the end, though, I have gone for PYcharm, which is about the bets, most full featured that there is. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/)! (a Java IDE) and installing [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) to make it a Python IDE

I have used this alot (but have since moved to PyCharm and sublime (the former of which is not free) and would highly recommend it.

This is freely available on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: a great choice... if you like eclipse the great tool. for some odd reason eclipse sometimes makes me reconsider if I want an IDE at all. I don't really know why, maybe it feels bloated and over-engineered?

Answer (score 5):

> **Important! This software is suggested using a web search and research. There is no personal experience involved using this
>   application. I hope my answer will help you anyway!**

I would like to recommend to use [Ninja-IDE](http://ninja-ide.org) And as per Wikipedia and their official website above features that I have mentioned below are available

- Light weight IDE
- Common functions such as: file handling, find in files code locator,
  go to line, tabs,
- automatic indentation, editor zoom, etc.
- **Multi-platform: Linux, Mac OS X, Windows.**
- Syntax highlighting for a wide variety of languages. Even though it
  is intended to be mainly a Python IDE, it can also handle several
  other languages.
- Static and PEP 8 error highlighting.
- **Show tips to help migrate code from Python2 to Python3.**
- Embedded Python console.
- Project management, allowing to add, modify and delete files and
  folders to projects, creating automatically the "**init**.py" files
  inside each module, etc.
- Allows to show/hide the panels of the interface in a very simple way
  to fit each programmer's preferences.
- Completely configurable UI.
- Allows using more than one editor at once.
- An extensible plug-in system, which creation the IDE supports.
- Session handling: remembers opened files and projects after closing
  the IDE.
- Code Auto-completion.
- Code Locator: Lets you jump to any code in your project with just a
  few keystrokes.

> For Ubuntu Users

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ninja-ide-developers/ninja-ide-stable (Stable updates)
(OR)
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ninja-ide-developers/daily (Daily updates)

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ninja-ide
```

Also I hope [this source](http://pedrokroger.net/choosing-best-python-ide/) will help you find a good IDE.

[image]

Anyway be warned that the support for python 3 is not complete, as the developer who built the Plug-in says here:

> I'm really happy to hear that you recommend this plugin. Unfortunately
>   the **support for python 3 was never finished (barely started)**,
>   although I believe it's not a lot of work, I could never finish it.
>   This past year has been crazy and I couldn't find the time to improve
>   the plugin with the new Ninja, if you or your friend would like to
>   contribute and perhaps create a pull request with the support for
>   python 3 that'll be awesome.

As Joaquin Sargiotto said you can contact him `joaquinsargiotto@gmail.com`
Github Profile: `https://github.com/jsargiot`

Comment: I was actually using it (+1), but the debugger plugin seems to be broken for Python3 as it uses Python2 style print statements, which are not compatible  :-(      File "/home/me/.ninja_ide/addins/plugins/debugger_plugin/ndb3/ndb3.py", line 92  
    print "Exception at debug: " + repr(e)  
                               ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Mawg Most of the time they might not reply but however I sent and email to the developers regarding this josecortes@ninja-ide.org, diego.sarmentero@ninja-ide.org

Comment: @Mawg I just got a reply for Dev Diego as he mentioned         The debugger plugin is not an official plugin, it was created for
someone from the community, so i can't provide any help there.
But we will have a complete support for debugging with lots of
features for NINJA-IDE 3.0.

Comment: @Mawg I was able to find the official developer who contributed for plugin,I've edited my post with the answer that I got from him

Comment: I want to write something in python now, just so I can try Ninja.  Their website is hilarious, and written by actual ninjas.   Stuff like:  "Ninja IDE is GPLv3. This doesn't stand for "Greatest Power Level", but it's pretty cool too."  http://ninja-ide.org/about/

Comment: Oh, yeeeaaah!!! real Ultimate Power !!   http://www.realultimatepower.net/

Comment: "But we will have a complete support for debugging with lots of features for NINJA-IDE 3.0" - where/when do I get that??? I volunteer to beta test. Gimme, gimme, gimme! I can haz Ninja v3?

Answer (score 4):

[Eric IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) features all of the items that you have requested, is free and cross platform, as I believe that the licence is very liberal.

If you are already an [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) user then there is the [pydev](http://pydev.org/) plugin that also offers all of the above.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Python_IDE says that the license is GPL v3, so I should be ok.  The screen-shots & feature lists look fine. I will give it a quick trial & get back to you.

Comment: Oops, I can't find a Debian package for Eric6  :-(

Comment: Once you have met the dependencies then you just download the .tag.gz file unpack it and follow the installation instructions for the prerequisites in the README file then run python install.py

Comment: Alas, I can't meet the dependencies. It requires Qt5 and we use Qt4 in our work. Although there should be no conflict, we are forbidden from adding other Qt versions "just in case".

Comment: Then use Eric 4 for python 2.x and Eric 5 for python 3.x! You should be able to find distributions for them still about.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [there is a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) that will certainly help you find what you need.

I would recommend [Komodo](http://komodoide.com/). I am not really sure about their terms, but there is an open-source version of this IDE, and it offers things like code completion, debugging tools and others.

Comment: Ah! For the days when S.O encouraged such questions ;-)  Thanks, @Victor, I will check these out & get back to you.

Comment: Looks like I can't use Komodo (http://komodoide.com/pricing/license-comparison/). I will look through the rest.