# IDE for IPython

Tags: python, ide, git

I am looking for an IDE for IPython that I want to use on windows with a git repository on Linux.

Desirable features: Git Plug-in, debugger, IPython support.

I'm not sure whether its use would be classified as commercial use. I do use it at work but we do not sell software, we're a hedge fund. Ideally it would be free.

I've been looking into Spyder and Ninja IDEs. Would you recommend one of them? Or any other alternative?

Comment: AFAIK, use it at work -> commercial use. (E.g. look at the [FAQ of VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs/faqs.html): "business and non profit use is considered commercial use")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't recommend [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) enough. It has [Git integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-git-integration.html) built in, has a great [debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debugging.html), and [supports IPython](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/ipython.html).

Unfortunately, I haven't used Spyder or Ninja to compare, but definitely give the free version of PyCharm a whirl.

Also, here's a [comparison page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in case you want to check out the pro version.

Comment: oh all right then ! is there any significant difference from the paid version ?

Comment: For me, the most important difference is added support for Django and Flask, but it really just depends on your usage. Here's a [comparison page](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: PyCharms Community Edition has Apache 2 license, so it should be ok for commercial use.

Comment: Fro differences between free & community editions, see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html  And, yes, the community edition, being Apache licensed is free for commercial use (as has been confirmed by JetBrains). See the answer to my question here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/gratis-python-ide-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 4):

Pycharm is excellent, but for exploratory data analysis I'm using Spyder.

Nice combination of variable exploration, ipython integration (rendering charts etc) and IDE features (code completion, code navigation etc)

Comment: Rendering charts in PyCharm doesn't work well ?

Comment: Spyder is really aimed a scientific and statistical users. Its a little like RStudio or the MATLAB editor. PyCharm's pure editing and debugging may be better though.

Comment: Just for completeness - if you use Visual Studio on Windows, it does support Python with the PTVS extension, and it does support git and github. It is quite huge and heavy for Python alone, though.